# JavaFx runnable JAR export is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, javafx, javafx-8

I've made a simple dictionary using JavaFX. I've used a SQLite Database and some pictures into my application. I exported the application as a runnable JAR file using e(fx) Eclipse. I followed the steps described here - https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1.

After exporting I opened the .JAR file. It opened successfully but wasn't working properly. It wasn't showing the results from the database and images.

When I ran the application into Eclipse workspace before building & exporting, it worked fine.

Where is the problem? How do I fix it?

Here is the code for the **Controller Class** function:

```
package imran.jfx.application;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Application_Controler implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private HBox hBox;

    @FXML
    private Label searchLabel;

    @FXML
    private TextField searchWord;

    @FXML
    private VBox vBox;

    @FXML
    private Text BanglaMeaning;

    @FXML
    private TextArea bnMeaningTxt;

    @FXML
    private Text bAcaMeaning;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane bAcaMeaningImg;

    @FXML
    private Label footerLabel;

    ResultSet result;
    PreparedStatement doQuery;
    Connection conn;
    String query;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String url="jdbc:sqlite:src/imran/ankurdb/meaning/bn_words.db";
        try 
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void showMeaning(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        bnMeaningTxt.clear();

        String text=searchWord.getText();

        query = "select en_word,bn_word from words where en_word='"+text+"'";

        doQuery = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        result = doQuery.executeQuery();

        int i=0;
        while (result.next()) 
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                bnMeaningTxt.appendText(result.getString(1) + "\t\t" + result.getString(2));
                i++;
            }
            else
                bnMeaningTxt.appendText(" , "+result.getString(2));
        }

        File file = new File("src/imran/bnacademy/meaning/"+text);
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        bAcaMeaningImg.setContent(new ImageView(image));
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code which you are using to load the images?

Comment: I've updated the post adding the code. Please check it now.

Comment: I am guessing these images are present inside your jar and if I am guessing it right you cannot use `File` to load images which are present inside your jar. You need to use the classloader to load them instead.

Comment: Then what about the database? Why the information is not showing from database?

Comment: That, again, depends on how are you creating the connection to the database in the first place. I would start debugging and check if the connection is established properly or not ;)

Comment: I've added the full code of my controller class. Can you now detect the problem?

Comment: You are trying to create a database file inside your project. This is not going to work when you have packaged your project as a Jar. You should give it a url outside your project. The database files should be placed always outside the project, so that when you package your project as a jar, they can still be created, read and written to.

Comment: A jar is an single archive file, it cannot contain other files. You need to load them as a resources.

Comment: Ok..I think I got it. Can please give me a sample code to make the image load working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

1. You are trying to create a database file inside your project. This is not going to work when you have packaged your project as a ***jar***. You should give it a `url` outside your project. The database files should be placed always outside the project, so that when you package your project as a jar, they can still be created, read and written to.
2. If the images are present inside your jar, you cannot use `io.File` to load images. You need to use the `class loader` to load them instead.

**Code**

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/imran/bnacademy/meaning/" + text);
Image image = new Image(url.toExternalForm());
```